# Changing xticks to the name of the months

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, series

i have a multilevel index series whose outer level index is month and inner level index is day let say it is stored in series

```
print(series)
```

Please see the output->[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxZ3D.png)

So to make plot i use the below code

```
series.plot.line(figsize=(20,10))
```

i am getting
please see the output->
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1WR3.png)

but i want xticks to be [January, February,......,December] instead of those tuple values how can i do that???

Comment: Some problem with my solution?

Comment: all months are not visible like november

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of use month only for display, maybe you should convert your `MultiIndex` (Month, Day) as `DatetimeIndex` for further analyze:

```
year = 2023 if len(series) == 365 else 2024  # leap year
dti = series.index.rename(['month', 'day']).to_frame().assign(year=year)
dti = pd.Index(pd.to_datetime(dti), name='Date')

series.index = dti
```

Output:

```
>>> series
Date
2023-01-01   -19.9
2023-01-02   -11.8
2023-01-03   -27.1
2023-01-04   -10.8
2023-01-05   -22.8
              ... 
2023-12-27   -26.9
2023-12-28   -12.9
2023-12-29   -10.2
2023-12-30   -15.1
2023-12-31   -29.4
Length: 365, dtype: float64
```

Now, you can use a formatter and a locator:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax = series.plot.line(rot=45)
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
formatter = mdates.DateFormatter('%B')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If need only months names is possible remove days from Multiindex by [`Series.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.droplevel.html) and convert to datetimes with [`DatetimeIndex.month_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month_name.html):

```
series.index = pd.to_datetime(series.index.droplevel(1), format='%m').month_name()
series.plot.line(figsize=(20,10))
```

Or if need more complex format, e.g. days with month names use [`matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) with convert `MulitIndex` to datetimes:

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

series.index = pd.to_datetime([f'2020-{m}-{d}' for m, d in series.index])
    
ax = series.plot.line(figsize=(20,10))

date_form = DateFormatter("%d-%B")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
```